# How I can calculate push/pull order cell in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im try to order cell like image, and this bootstrap code are do that, but Im still try & test to get this order, is there any way to calculate push or pull for each col in grid .

my question with another way, I need to order cell, to i can print a cell like image, im try & test many of value for pull/push to get this code ..is there way to calculate value?

```html
<div class="row row-4">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-push-9">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-push-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-pull-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-pull-7">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-pull-11">1</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It's working.. if you see it here : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/jqu5hghc/embedded/result/

Comment: yes mate, its working, ^_^, sorry my English is very bad, I mean in this question .. Im do test for 10 time to get this final result .. to i know is push-9, push-2 ...ets im test a value for each one, then check it in browser, finally Im set this value and its work fine .. know what i need .. how i can calculate push/pull value directly ... example 12col - xs3 = push-9 ..then i set push-9 in first div but when fo to second 12col-4 = push8 and its false .....like this ...

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering this code, and our 12 columns :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">1</div>
</div>
```

We've got:

```
+---+-----------------+------------------+------------+---------+
| ° | Wanted position | Current position | Difference | Class   |
+---------------------+------------------+------------+---------|
| 1 | 1               | 12 (1+3+4+1+3)   | -11        | pull-11 |
| 2 | 2  (1+1)        | 9  (1+3+4+1)     | -7         | pull-7  |
| 3 | 5  (1+1+3)      | 8  (1+3+4)       | -3         | pull-3  |
| 4 | 6  (1+1+3+1)    | 4  (1+3)         | +2         | push-2  |
| 5 | 10 (1+1+3+1+4)  | 1                | +9         | push-9  |
+---+-----------------+------------------+------------+---------+
```

Picture time :

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice answer, but Bootstrap columns use relative positioning.

Comment: @Christina My bad. Using `left` and `right` doesn't mean using absolute positioning. I removed the related line.